# How do I scroll down when there are multiple windows within a browser that has scroll bars using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

So after clicking a button the pop up window (in the picture) popped up, and it has 2 elements with scroll bars. I want to scroll down on the main, right, element.

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 10000)","")
```

This line of code does not work. It did not throw an error, but it had no effect.

Comment: Are those name rows are in a table? if not what is the parent of all those rows? We can scroll based on the rows if we know the parent and row html

Comment: @supputuri How do I find out if the rows are in the table? how do I find out of the parents of the rows?

Comment: If not you have to click on inspect in dev tools and move the move above the first row, until all the rows are highlight. That's the parent element we need.

Comment: @supputuri I've included a picture of the HTML

Comment: I counted 28 rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192822/discussion-between-supputuri-and-athletic-coder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the logic to scroll and perform operations on each row.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@clas='pagec_list_wrapper]/div[@class='pagelist_item])[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@clas='pagec_list_wrapper]/div[@class='pagelist_item])[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view

# get the number of rows
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@clas='pagec_list_wrapper]/div[@class='pagelist_item]")
# now you can access each row here in for loop
for rowNumber in range(len(rows)):
    # scroll to the row
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@clas='pagec_list_wrapper]/div[@class='pagelist_item])[" + str(rowNumber+1) "]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # if you want to click on the button (+) for that user
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[@clas='pagec_list_wrapper]/div[@class='pagelist_item])[" + str(rowNumber+1) "]//span[@class='ui_button_icon'])[1]").click()
    # you can use row element for any action with in the row
    row.xxxxxx
```

Comment: This code returns a list of 8 rows. So if I for loop throw the returned list, then I would only be able to hit 8 buttons. But I want to hit more. How can I get access to more than 8 rows? This is why I need to scroll down

Comment: Updated the answer.